# three.js Raycaster intersectObjects

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to modify [this example](https://github.com/timoxley/threejs/blob/master/examples/webgl_morphtargets_md2_control.html) from three.js to control the character(s) with mouse clicks.  First, when I click on the canvas, I need the mouse coordinates and convert that into 3D space coordinates using THREE.Raycaster.intersectObjects.  In the modified code, on left mouse up, I have the following:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
var projector = new THREE.Projector();
projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);

if (intersects.length > 0) {
    console.log('intersect: ' + intersects[0].point.x.toFixed(2) + ', ' + intersects[0].point.y.toFixed(2) + ', ' + intersects[0].point.z.toFixed(2) + ')');
}
else {
    console.log('no intersect');
}
```

I have added the ground mesh to the `objects` array, but `raycaster.intersectObjects` still returns empty array when I click on the ground mesh.  I also tried passing in `scene.children` instead of `objects`, but no luck.

Here is the [full modified source](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5225890).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Gyroscope is the problem.  Taking out these lines, and I get intersects working.  Not sure if this is a bug or feature.

```
var gyro = new THREE.Gyroscope();
gyro.add( camera );
characters[ Math.floor( nSkins/2 ) ].root.add( gyro );
```